# android studio app.i want to enable and show input text when button is on and disable and hide it when button is off

Tags: java, android

I am new in android studio andworking on android app. where i want to enable editdi text when button is on, and disable it when button is off.
in edittext i want to give time interval for which button will be on and then it will be off when given time ends.
If anybody know the solution, kindly inform me.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Please Provide some code if you are talking about simple button then please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you are using ToggleButton, take help of [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). Please use below code snippet it will help.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText);
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            editText.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            editText.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){

    public void run() {
            toggle.setChecked(false); //setting button off after time interval ends.
    }
}

timer.schedule(task, 1000); // time is for 1 sec after that TimerTask run method will be called.
```

Now you can start this Timer whenever you need with the time duration you want. The time provided while calling schedule method is in milliseconds.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Afraz did it help??

Comment: @Afraz Could you please consider up-voting the answer if it helps :)

Comment: yes thank you so much 
you made my work easier...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buuton);

EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

if(editText.getText.toString.length()>0){

btn.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
}

else{

btn.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBle);

}